# Accessing UIBezierCurve values between user defined two points

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibezierpath

I'm trying to create an iPad app that can display bezier curves between user defined points/keyframes.

As an example keyframe1 has a coordinate of x: 0, y: 0 and keyframe2 has a coordinate of x: 100, Y: 100.

I want to create/display a Bezier Curve in between keyframe 1 and 2. The problem is, I don't know how to read and save the values of the curve.

Can someone point me in the right direction of doing this, I already figured out how to create the points/coordinates/keyframes and the UIBezierPath with curved lines. Is there a method/function/option to retrieve the values from the curve between the two points?

I was thinking of creating/adding a lot of points on top of the UIBezierCurve to give the curve resolution, meaning more points the more accurate data I can retrieve from the UIBezierCurve when I iterate through the points and get their co-ordinates.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a good algorithm for creating cubic or quadratic bezier curves from existing points. It's a very difficult problem, since the middle control points are not on the curve.

There is another kind of spline called a Catmull Rom spline that is much better for fitting a curve to a set of control points.

You can use Catmull Rom splines to take a series of line segments and convert it to more line segments that closely approximate a smooth curve. Thus you can create a UIBezierPath that is actually a series of short line segments.

The (outstanding) Erica Sadun book "The iOS 6 Developers' Cookbook" has a recipe that shows how to use them. I would suggest that approach.

Comment: I found addCurveToPoint in the Apple SDK Documentation instead of using addLineToPoint, which gives me the nice curves AND control handles for free. Now I got that solved, I now need to figure out how to get the values from the Curve.